# C# cloud firestore retrieve an array

Tags: c#, firebase, visual-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve the array of cpu_ids but it throws

System.InvalidCastException: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' 'System.Array'.
[image]

my code

```
    public static async Task RetriveDataFromFirestore(string email, string digitalkey)
    {    

       
            Query collection = Database.Collection("customers").Document(UserId).Collection("subscriptions");
            QuerySnapshot subscriptions = await collection.GetSnapshotAsync();

            foreach(DocumentSnapshot use in subscriptions)
            {
                DocumentReference docref = Database.Collection("customers").Document(UserId).Collection("subscriptions").Document(use.Id.ToString());
                DocumentSnapshot snap = await docref.GetSnapshotAsync();

                
                if (snap.Exists)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> key = snap.ToDictionary();
                    
                    foreach (var item in key)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(item);
                        if (item.Key == "cpu_ids")
                        {
                            foreach (var stoixeio in (Array)item.Value)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(stoixeio);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
```

Comment: Please could you post the complete stack trace, and ideally a [mcve]? (The exception looks a little odd with all those question marks... any ideas where those have come from?) I doubt that this is really related to Visual Studio, so I'd suggest removing that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```cs
foreach (var stoixeio in (Array)item.Value)
```

You're casting `item.Value` to an array, but it's not an array. It's a list. As per the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest/datamodel.html), the default type of a Firestore array is a `List<object>`. So just cast to a `List<object>` instead of `Array` (or even just cast to the non-generic `IEnumerable` type) and it should be fine.